# C# VS2010 IDE : Dynamic properties for control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm working on an "Action Command System..." and i 'm a bit lost with visual studio IDE designer.

The picture below try to show you what i want to do !

I think i can handle some part of that
but i don't know how to do the red square part (managing dynamic properties in Design Time)... So if u have clue , let me know !!

So question is mostly about doing that only with Designer, not by code !
[image]

*On ActAddBook button click : the action AddBook event is called, and take parameter from button properties set up in DESIGN TIME (or during execution time but only if i need to change dynamicly a parameter*

The point his, Action Manager and Forms are in different project / dll ...
Action Manager manage action for the entire application...
Controls like button are Class that inherits from Control (exemple Button) and  implement IActionSender;

What i want mostly is Design Editor in VS 2010 for both ACTION manager and Action Controls.

i dont know how to manage metadata to do that if its possible
graphically that would be :

```
**Properties**          **Value**

  Action            « Drop Down List of all actions in Action Manager »
+ Parameters    
    Param1<<string> “propertie name” ex : this.textedit1.text
    Param2<<Book>>  “propertie name” ex : this.grid1.currentRow
```

So, after some reserching :

I've discovered the IExtenderProvider that is great for adding some property to controls !

But now here is my second problem : How to "share" some objects thought each form without inherited !

Let me explain what i want to do, for example with a List

At Design Time

I want to have a "form" or something else (no matter what) that can add strings to the List

=> First Component "StringManager"

On the other hand i want to have *another Component* that use **IExtenderProvider** and add on All controls (in the component form) a property named "*TheString*" which let me choose in **one of the string from List**

So, to be clear : i want to share *List* !

I think of Static List or something else, maybe XML file...?

Of course all of that is at **Design Time**, not at Execution Time (it would be simpler !!)

*That would be a first step...*

*The Second step* is about changing the list to a list

Action is object which contains some property like parameters ...

*The third step* is during execution time, the Action Manager should reference itself on each Control that use actions , lets see that later !

Thanks

Comment: Please be more clear. I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: OK, i've have few informations on the main subject, in terms of design pattern, its about Command and Mediator togheter

Comment: @Bgnt44: that's not "more clear"

Comment: tell me what you want to know ?

Comment: Seriously, if you had to explain this to yourself? How would you explain it? If you had to explain it to another developer, how would you explain it? I can't believe even _you_ could understand your own question!

Comment: I've add some details for what i want .

Comment: Finally! I've removed my downvote and I'll see if I can help.